# Как продолжить выполнение программы Python при ошибке в цикле FOR?

Tags: python, try

Нужно, чтобы при любой ошибке в любой из функций - выждать 5 сек и продолжить выполнение, не переходя на следующий цикл, с тем же ftid.
Сейчас, в случае ошибки, будет пропуск отработки функций с этим ftid.
Как сделать максимально правильно.

```
for ftid in range(begin_ftid, end_ftid):
        try:
           f1(ftid)
           f2(ftid)
           f3(ftid)
              
        except Exception:
            time.sleep(5)
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой вариант так сказать:

```py
for ftid in range(10):
    b = True
    while b: #Повторять пока b = True
        try:
           f1(ftid)
           f2(ftid)
           f3(ftid)
           b = False # если все хорошо прерываем цикл while
        except Exception: # иначе выполнится исключение и b останется True
            time.sleep(1)
            pass
```

Comment: Отличное решение, благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Для таких вещей есть удобные декораторы, например [retry](https://github.com/invl/retry). Правда, придётся описать ещё одну функцию, чтобы использовать декоратор:

```
@retry(delay=5)
def f123(ftid):
    f1(ftid)
    f2(ftid)
    f3(ftid)

for ftid in range(begin_ftid, end_ftid):
    f123(ftid)
```

Таким образом, за счёт использования декоратора мы убрали из кода:

- цикл `while`
- `try-except`
- `time.sleep`

Там есть довольно удобные настройки - например, можно увеличивать паузу между попытками, можно ограничить число попыток, ловить только определённые исключения, добавлять случайную задержку.